# get_user_by('ID',7) works for users but not admins

Tags: php, wordpress, intranet

I'm bumping into this issue where if I login as a user, the function works and pulls up the info that I need but if I login as an admin it returns bool(false). Any clue as to why is this happening?

This is on a folder on the root of the project in which /wp-config.php and /wp-includes/wp-db.php have been included. Is this normal behavior?

Thanks

EDIT:

For those asking what 7 is, it's just an example user_id but obviously I'm bringing it from somewhere else where it works.

All in all get_user_by is a Wordpress API function that yields results when I'm logged in as a user but not when I'm logged in as an admin for whatever reason.

Comment: What is `7` there . ?

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: @VaibhavBhanushali That's just an example. As to not write get_user_by(ID) like some other question has.

Comment: @dass This refers to a Wordpress API function. It's crystal clear. There is no extra code that I can provide that can help you understand the issue. This is in the inner workings of Wordpress.

Comment: Have you tried to get this info on another page? (E.g. a simple template page, that shows only the user data you are after.) If yes, and you do not experience the same problem, then it's the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the following file included, that's why the function didn't work on other custom made pages.

```
wp-includes/pluggable.php
```